# How to indicate in notes that the next slide/animation should be shown?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Like most presenters, I'll often setup bullet points with animation so that one appears at a time as I click.

Currently, I am manually typing ***Click*** at each point in my notes that I need to click for the next bullet point or slide.

Is there a built-in method in PowerPoint of notating where in the notes a new slide or bullet point is to be loadedd?

Comment: How would PowerPoint know where in the flow of notes *you* want to advance each animation?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - That's what I'm asking, really. Is there any built-in standard way of indicating (to me) that it's time to advance the animation/slideshow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerPoint doesn't offer a built-in way to tell the presenter when to activate manually-triggered events such as animations and slide changes. Manually triggered events are meant to be triggered at the discretion of the presenter. Every presentation is different, so this is desirable.

When a presentation is not dependant on variable factors, PowerPoint can be configured to trigger events automatically using timers. This is useful when the timing between events, such as fading-in multiple bullet points on a slide, is known in advance.

Comment: I see. As a new presenter, I rely on a "reminder" to change slides and advance the slideshow, otherwise I may get ahead of the slides. I will just continue writing in a reminder manually. Thank you.